# How to remove apostrophe s ('s) from end of string

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove "'s" from end of string, but cannot get it to work in PHP.

I found this on SO:

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
// search forward starting from end minus needle length characters
    return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== false);
}
```

I tried calling it, like this:

```
endsWith($word,"'s");
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work for words that end with 's, such as:

```
$word = "mom's";
$word = "dad's";
```

Any suggestion much appreciated. Regex is an option too, I'm not fussy!

EDIT: removed extra ' from "mom's" (sorry!)

Comment: str_replace should help

Comment: Downvotes, really? Seemed like a fair question to me. :)

Comment: Turns out the apostrophe was being encoded, so thanks to Chris I used this and problem was solved:  $word = rtrim($word,"&#39;s");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function should work for you.

```
echo rtrim($word,"'s");
```

Demo: https://eval.in/627045

Comment: Thanks Chris, demo works perfectly, but in my code it appears to detect the 's correctly at the end of string but for some reason rtrim will only remove the "s". For example, "dad's" becomes "dad'". Ever seen this before?

Comment: Is it a real quote, maybe it is the entity `&#39;`? Behavior seems consistent across PHP versions. https://3v4l.org/1DcbY

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 2):

Try preg_replace:

```
preg_replace("/\'s$/", "", $word);
```

This will eliminate ONLY a string ending with `'s`, like `mom's`. No period at the end, nothing else.

To replace all of them, try:

```
preg_replace("/\'s/", "", $word);
```

Comment: The single quote doesn't need to be escaped when inside double quotes.

Comment: Habit from C programming