# Remove s or 's from all words in a string with PHP

Tags: php

I have a string in PHP

```
$string = "Dogs are Jonny's favorite pet";
```

I want to use regex or some method to remove `s` or `'s` from the end of all words in the string.

The desired output would be:

```
$revisedString = "Dog are Jonny favorite pet";
```

Here is my current approach:

```
<?php

$string = "Dogs are Jonny's favorite pet";

$stringWords = explode(" ", $string);
$counter = 0;
foreach($stringWords as $string) {

     if(substr($string, -1) == s){
         $stringWords[$counter] = trim($string, "s");
     }
  
    if(strpos($string, "'s") !== false){
       $stringWords[$counter] = trim($string, "'s");
    }
    
    $counter = $counter + 1;
}

print_r($stringWords);

$newString = "";
foreach($stringWords as $string){
   $newString = $newString . $string . " ";
}

echo $newString;
}


?>
```

How would this be achieved with REGEX?

Comment: All `s` / `'s` or just those at the end of a word, parky Johnon?

Comment: those at the end of a word (plurals or possessives)

Comment: It would be difficult/impossible to do this without using an English dictionary, to distinguish plural `s` from another word whose final `s` is part of the word.

Comment: You'd also have to consider the possessive apostrophe on plural nouns, eg _"the twins’ parents"_

Comment: True about plurals, but for my purposes just removing s and 's will be sufficient

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that will remove all "s" characters, not just those at the end of words

Comment: I'd go with something like `preg_replace("/'?s\b/", "", $string)` if you want a simple regex that will probably get it wrong for edge cases

Comment: Me too, @Phil.  Please write your resolving advice as an answer (with fine print that explains that it is "English-ignorant").  I might even do a negative lookbehind for another `s` if not a possessive or contraction.

Comment: @mickmackusa I've already voted to close so not going to answer, especially with something I know will be very wrong in a lot of cases

Comment: Hmm.  I can't get behind NMF.  Can you help me to rationalize how it is asking multiple questions, @Phil ?

Comment: @mickmackusa I've long ignored the text on that vote and refer to its core message of simply needing more focus / the question is too broad. [And I'm not the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402523/283366)

Comment: I've answered, but I can always revert that decision. This is related, but not a suitable solution/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39083154/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general use, you must leverage much more sophisticated technique than an English-ignorant regex pattern.  There may be fringe cases where the following pattern fails by removing an `s` that it shouldn't.  It could be a name, an acronym, or something else.

As an unreliable solution, you can optionally match an apostrophe then match a literal `s` if it is not immediately preceded by another `s`.  Adding a word boundary (`\b`) on the end improves the accuracy that you are matching the end of words.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cY9Rq))

```
$string = "The bass can access the river's delta from the ocean. The fishermen, assassins, and their friends are happy on the banks";

var_export(preg_replace("~'?(?<!s)s\b~", '', $string));
```

Output:

```
'The bass can access the river delta from the ocean. The fishermen, assassin, and their friend are happy on the bank'
```

Comment: This still incorrectly removes the final _s_  from words like *abacus*, *osmosis*, and *porous*.

Comment: Indeed.  I state that this solution is English-ignorant.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thankfully for my use case, abacus, osmosis, and porous will still return from "abacu", "osmosi", and "porou" in a database query